# When clicking on a button I want the number to change

Tags: javascript, web

I don't know a lot about programming but I needed help with something. For example when someone click on a button I want that the number in the button changes like if it was 1 it will become 2 and so on

If its possible please give me the HTML CODE and the JavaScript

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple `to code`
[Click here for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke5zq/)

Comment: If the answer was useful please +1 the answer by clicking the UP Arrow so that it will help others too. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply a simple logic. On the button click event, get the number value, add +1 to it and then display.